# How to parse grouped nested dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift5, jsonparser

I am trying to parse the below JSON response in SWIFT5, but I am getting nil values for the user and group data.

```
{
    "user": {
        "0": {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "ABC"
        }
    },
    "group": {
        "0": {
            "id": "510",
            "name": "XYZ"
        }
    }
}


if let unwrappedData = data {

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                        print(json)

                        if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self,from:unwrappedData){
                            completion(.success(user))
                            
                        }else{
                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse.errorValue))
                        }
                    }catch{
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
```

The user data is printing as nil. How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code in playground and it works like charm, what is the issue in json?

**Data Model**

```
// MARK: - Sample
struct Sample: Codable {
    let user, group: Group
}

// MARK: - Group
struct Group: Codable {
    let the0: The0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the0 = "0"
    }
}

// MARK: - The0
struct The0: Codable {
    let id, name: String
}
```

**Json Data**

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "user": {
        "0": {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "ABC"
        }
    },
    "group": {
        "0": {
            "id": "510",
            "name": "XYZ"
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)
```

**Json Parsing**

```
if let data = jsonData {
        let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Sample.self, from: data)
        print("Json Object", object)
}
else {
    print("Bad Json")
}
```

**Output**

```
Json Object Optional(SwiftPlayground.Sample(user: SwiftPlayground.Group(the0: SwiftPlayground.The0(id: "5", name: "ABC")), group: SwiftPlayground.Group(the0: SwiftPlayground.The0(id: "510", name: "XYZ"))))
```